Can Chaos be encountered multiple times in a single night?
Is it possible to encounter Chaos multiple times in a single night in Hades II? I've only encountered him once per run so far.

It's possible to meet them several times a night. A Chaos Door may appear by itself several times during a run, and it's also possible to force the apparition of yet another door by buying a Spark of Ixion in a Well of Charon.

Does that mean you can have 2 negative effects from Chaos at the same time?

It's indeed possible, for instance by buying the Spark of Ixion item from the Well of Charon shop while still running under the negative effect of a previous Chaos Gate.

Amusingly, after asking this question I encountered Chaos 4 times in a single night. I tried to be clever and had two "Next boons are common" effects at the same time, but boons only counted towards one curse.
